# Import modules and export at runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

Hi i have two config file, eg.:

*config-one.ts*

```
export const FOO = '1';
export const BAR = 1;
```

*config-two.ts*

```
export const FOO = '2';
export const BAR = 2;
```

both files are imported in config.ts.

*config.ts*

```
import * as configOne from './config-one.ts';
import * as configTwo from './config-two.ts';
```

I want at some contition export config-one or config-two like as exported by *config.ts*

```
if ( some condition ){
    export configOne;
} else {
    export configTwo;
}
```

usage in other file

*foo.ts*

```
import { FOO, BAR } from './config.ts';
```

Is possible in typescript?

Comment: `export configOne;` is not legal in ES6 modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic import is enough to make dynamic export happen:

config-one.ts

```
export const config1 = "config1";
```

config-two.ts

```
export const config2 = "config2";
```

index.ts

```
const whatever = true;

const getConfig = () => {
  if (whatever) {
    return import("./config-one");
  }
  return import("./config-two");
};
```

tsconfig

```
...
"moduleResolution": "Node",
"module": "CommonJS",
...
```

usage example:

```
async function main() {
  console.log(await getConfig());
}

main().catch(console.log);
```